# if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n \in [c,b]$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \in [c,b]$ not understanding the contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

> if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n  \in [c,b]$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \in [c,b]$

I just wanted to make sure I was writing a correct proof and communicating my ideas correctly.

**Proof**

Suppose $a \notin [c,b]$. Given that $a_n \rightarrow a$ this means: $$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow \ \exists \ a_n \ s.t. \ a_n \notin [c,b]$$

Not sure if I have to give this explanation after, but since $a_n$ converges to $a$ it means eventually that $a_n$ and $a$ are going to be so close or equal that   $a_n$ will not be able to be in $[c,b]$

**EDIT 2 - Revised with correct solution**

I'm going to leave up my original solution as well so others can possibly see the difference between what would be considered a sound proof VS one that is not even if you may have the right idea.

*Proof*

Let $\epsilon >0$ and let $a < c  \Leftrightarrow 0 < c-a$.

Given that $a_n \rightarrow a$ this means: 
$$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

Since the claim of convergence has to work **for all** $\epsilon$, consider $\epsilon = \frac{c-a}{2}$

Since $a_n \rightarrow a$:

$$|a_n - a| < \epsilon = \frac{c-a}{2}\\ \Rightarrow \\ \frac{-(c-a)}{2} + a < a_n < \frac{c-a}{2} + a = \frac{c}{2} + \frac{a}{2} $$

We assumed $ a < c$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{c}{2} + \frac{a}{2} < \frac{c}{2} + \frac{c}{2} = c$$
$$\therefore  a_n < \frac{c}{2} + \frac{a}{2} < c  \\ \Rightarrow \ a_n \notin [c,b] \ \forall \  n \geq N$$

But one of our assumptions is that $a_n \in [c,b]$. So we have a contradiction.

Comment: Shouldn't the interval $[c,b]$ be  actually $[b,c]$?

Comment: @Bernard that doesn't matter in this sense. $c$ and $b$ are just arbitrary numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as you wrote it, there's no contradiction in having $a>c$, whereas there is one  with $[b,c]$.

Comment: @Bernard ok, going with [b,c] as the interval. I suppose the contradiction would be the one I'm trying to see in the discussion below? ....which for the life of me I am still not finding...

Comment: "Not sure if I have to give this explanation after, but since an converges to a it means eventually that an and a are going to be so close or equal that an will not be able to be in [c,b]"  I think this is skirting around the idea that if $a \not \in [c,b]$ then $\inf \{|a-k|: k \in [c,b]\} > 0$ and so when $|a_n - a| < \epsilon = \inf \{|a-k|: k \in [c,b]\}$ we can conclude $a_n \not \in [c,b]$.  .... This is acceptable but you must demonstrate that if if $a \not \in [c,b]$ then $\inf \{|a-k|: k \in [c,b]\} > 0$.  Which is *not* a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a>b$. Then for $ \epsilon =\frac{a-b}{2}>0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N$ we have $ \ |a_n - a| < \frac{a-b}{2}$.

But then this means: $ a-\frac{a-b}{2}<a_n < a+\frac{a-b}{2}$

Looking at the left-hand side we see: $ b=\frac{b+b}{2}<\frac{b+a}{2}=a-\frac{a-b}{2}<a_n$ for all $ \ n \geq N$.

Do you see the contradiction now?

Can you do the same for $a<c$?

Comment: is it that $\frac{b+a}{2} < \frac{a-b}{2}$ ???

Comment: No. It is that we supposed $a_n$'s are always in the interval $[c,b]$. So they have to be smaller than $b$ but at the end we find $a_n>b$ starting a certain rank $N$.

Comment: In your last sentence did you mean $a_n > b$ starting at a certain $N$?

Comment: @dc3rd Yes I corrected it.

Comment: Ok.....so in my original proof before the edit, this was the exact idea that I envisioned I was communicating. So because I didn't explicitly illustrate this contradiction is that why my proof is weak?.......I guess I also have to consider the order of my interval to get the right contradictions too...also, if I'm looking at the distance between the two points, why would I not use the absolute value form? $\frac{|a-b||}{2}$?

Comment: @dc3rd Yes. Basically you describe the idea of the proof without explicitly explaining a way to find such an $a_n$ that is not in the interval. That is not acceptable. You don't convince the reader you understand why such $a_n$'s 
would exist. Taking $(a-b)/2$ for $\epsilon$ works but so would have $(a-b)/4$ etc. You need to show you understand the meaning of definition and actually use it.

Comment: John11 has said better what i was saying last night (before I went to sleep).

Comment: Thank you  for your help John. I'm not going to forget using the half distance trick now for certain epsilon questions.

Comment: Sorry for not completely getting what you said @Randall, but introducing the half distance trick definitely helped. Since it has to work for all epsilon, if I choose an "arbitrary" one then it better work for that one or like in this scenario I get a contradiction.

Comment: How is the rewritten solution @John11 ?

Comment: @dc3rd perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. If $a\notin [c,b]$ then $a\in [c,b]^c,$ which is an open set in $\mathbb R.$ So, $a$ is either contained in some open interval to the left of $c$ or to the right of $b$. Drawing a picture will help.

Let's say $a$ is in the center of an interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\beta<c.$ Now, since $a_n\to a$, it must be the case that, if $n$ is large enough, all $a_n$ land in $(\alpha, \beta).$ More precisely: let $\epsilon =\frac{\beta -\alpha }{2}$. Then, there is an integer $N$ such that if $n>N$, $|a-a_n|<\epsilon=\frac{\beta -\alpha }{2}.$ This means that $-\frac{\beta -\alpha }{2}<a-a_n<\frac{\beta -\alpha }{2}$ so the distance between $a$ and $a_n$ is less than half the width of the interval $(\alpha,\beta).$ That is to say, the $a_n$ are in $(\alpha, \beta),\ $ which is a contradiction because $(\alpha, \beta)$  is disjoint from $[c,b]$ by construction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of proving that $a \in [c,b]$, prove that if $k \not \in [c,b]$ then $k \ne a$.

If $k < c$ and $a_n \in [c,b]$ then $a_n \ge c > k$ and $|a_n - k| = a_n - k = (a_n -c) + (c-k) \ge c-k > 0$.  So for $\epsilon = c-k$ then $|a_n - k| \ge \epsilon$ for all $a_n$.  So $a_n \not \to k$.

Likewise if $k > b$ and $a_n \in [c,b]$ then $k > b \ge a_n$ and  $|a_n - k| = k- a_n = (k-b) + (b-a_n) \ge k-b > 0$.  So for $\epsilon = k - b$ then $|a_n - k| \ge \epsilon$ for all $a_n$.  So $a_n \not \to k$.

So if $k \not \in [c,b]$ then $a_n \not \to k$.

So if $a_n \to a$ by contrapositive $a \in [c,b]$.